# How to update @ObservedObject object while adding items to the class

Tags: swift

I have 2 sections (ingredients selection and ingredient added). In the ingredient selection, i get all items from a json file. The goal is whenever i chose an ingredient from the ingredient selection, the item should be  added to the ingredient added section. However the actual result is that I am able to add all ingredients in `AddedIngredients`. However my `@ObservedObject var ingredientAdded :AddedIngredients` indicates no items, so nothing in the section.

What am I missing in my logic?
Is it because the `@Published var ingredients = [Ingredient]()` is from a struct which creates a new struct every time ? My understanding is that since `AddedIngredients` is a class, it should reference the same date unless I override it.

This my model:

```
import Foundation

struct Ingredient: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let price: String
    let ajoute: Bool
}

class AddedIngredients: ObservableObject {


    @Published var ingredients = [Ingredient]()
}
```

The ingredient section that displays all ingredients:

```
struct SectionIngredientsSelection: View {
    let ingredients: [Ingredient]
    @StateObject var ajoute = AddedIngredients()
    var body: some View {
        Section(header: VStack {
            Text("Ajouter vos ingredients")

        }) {
            ForEach(ingredients){ingredient in
                HStack{
                    HStack{
                        Image("mais")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        Text(ingredient.id)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    HStack{
                        Text(ingredient.price )
                        Button(action: {
                            ajoute.ingredients.append(ingredient)
                            print(ajoute.ingredients.count)
                        }){
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                                .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.3257463574, blue: 0, alpha: 1)))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .listRowBackground(Color.white)
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I add an ingredient from the previous section, it should appear on this section.

```
struct SectionIngredientsSelected: View {
    @ObservedObject var ingredientAdded :AddedIngredients
        var body: some View {
            Section(header: VStack {
                HStack{
                    Text("Vos ingredients")
                        .textCase(nil)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)

                    Button(action: {print(ingredientAdded.ingredients.count)}, label: {Text("Add")})
                }
            }) {
                ForEach(ingredientAdded.ingredients){ingredient in
                    HStack{
                        HStack{
                            Image("mais")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                            Text(ingredient.id)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        HStack{
                            Text(ingredient.price )
                            Button(action: {
                            }){
                                Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.3257463574, blue: 0, alpha: 1)))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color.white)
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            }
        }
    }
```

Main View

```
struct CreationView: View {
    let ingredients: [Ingredient] = Bundle.main.decode("Ingredients.json")
    var addedIngre: AddedIngredients
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack{
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Image("creation")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                    Text("Slectionnez vos ingredients preferes").fontWeight(.light)
                    Divider()
                        .padding(.bottom)
                }
            }
        }
        List {
            SectionIngredientsSelected(ingredientAdded: addedIngre)
            SectionIngredientsSelection(ingredients: ingredients)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating two different instances of `AddedIngredients`. These do not synchronize their content with each other. The simpelest solution would be to pull the `AddedIngredients` up into `CreationView` and pass it down to the sub views.

So change your `CreationView` to:

```
struct CreationView: View {
    let ingredients: [Ingredient] = Bundle.main.decode("Ingredients.json")
    @StateObject private var addedIngre: AddedIngredients = AddedIngredients()
```

and:

```
SectionIngredientsSelected(ingredientAdded: addedIngre)
SectionIngredientsSelection(ingredients: ingredients, ajoute: addedIngre)
```

and `SectionIngredientsSelection` to:

```
struct SectionIngredientsSelection: View {
    let ingredients: [Ingredient]
    @ObservedObject var ajoute: AddedIngredients
```

Remarks:

It is not perfectly clear for me how `CreationView` aquires `addedIngre`. From your code it seems it gets somehow injected. If this is the case and you need it upward the view hierachy, change the `@StateObject` to `@ObservedObject`. But make sure it is initialized with `@StateObject`.

Comment: Thanks your reply, I tried your steps and it works. So the `@StateObject `should have been on my main view, while the others should have been an `@ObservedObject `.